# #id conflict while generating/removing divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to setup a script that allows a user to generate up to 4 divs (each containing an input and a span) and the ability to remove them.

```js
var i = 1;
$(".submit-source .add-source").click( function() {
 i++;
 source = jQuery('<div id="source-wrap-' + i + '" class="source-wrap" ><input name="source-' + i + '" type="text"/><span class="remove-source">remove</span></div>');
 source.insertAfter(".submit-source .source-wrap:last");
    
 if (i == 4) {
  $(".submit-source .add-source").hide();
 }
 else {
  $(".submit-source .add-source").show();
 }
} );
$(document).on("click", ".submit-source .remove-source", function() {
 i--;
 $(this).parent().remove();
    
 if (i == 4) {
  $(".submit-source .add-source").hide();
 }
 else {
  $(".submit-source .add-source").show();
 }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="submit-source">
 <span>Add up to 4 different sources.</span>
 <div id="source-wrap-1" class="source-wrap" >
  <input name="source-1" type="text"/>
 </div>
 <span class="add-source">add input</span>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that, for instance, if 4 divs are generated and the user removes the 2nd or 3rd one and then generates a new one, he ends up with 2 divs with the same id (and same for the input names inside theses divs).

How can I improve my script so a generated input will check if the previous inputs exist ? For instance it won't generate a new #source-wrap-4 if this one already exists, but instead generate #source-wrap-3 if this div doesn't exist or is removed).

I don't want it to go past #source-wrap-4 (and source-4 for the input name) so I can handle the inputs easily with php when retrieving the data.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Why do you need to give them ids at all? Just keep the elements in an array.

Comment: It was mostly for more clarity but indeed it isn't necessary. Nevertheless I still need to work this out because the inputs inside theses divs need different names

Comment: Since you have a finite (and small) number of possible elements, why not generate all of them, with sequential IDs, but hide and show them as the user "removes" and "adds" them. When you hide them, also disable them, which prevents them from being submitted with the form.

Comment: haha, yes that's the way it was initially :) I'm coding mostly to learn right now so I decided to change it for something more dynamic, more pro, but it is harder than I thought.

Comment: @eloism See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By keeping the available ids in an array, you can be sure not to reuse anything you shouldn't.

Also, your if/then logic is identical in both your add and your remove functions, so they were isolated to remove duplication.

```js
// Store available ids
var availableIDs = [2,3,4];

const NOT_AVAIL = "ID_UNAVAILABLE";

// This function returns the first element in the aray
// If the array no longer has any available elements,
// it returns "ID_UNAVAILABLE". You can incorporate that 
// into the code to ensure that only 4 elements can be made at max
function getID(){
  if(availableIDs.length > 0){  
    // return the first element in the array and remove that element
    // from the array
    return availableIDs.shift();
  } else {
    return NOT_AVAIL;
  }
}

$(".submit-source .add-source").click( function() {
    // Get the next available ID
    var newID = getID();
  
    // As long as the new ID is not "ID_UNAVAILABLE", proceed:
    if(newID !== NOT_AVAIL){
   source = $('<div id="source-wrap-' + newID + 
                      '" class="source-wrap" ><input name="source-' + newID + 
                      '" type="text"/><span class="remove-source">remove</span></div>');
  
   source.insertAfter(".submit-source .source-wrap:last");
     
      var theID = $(source).attr("id");
      var theLastChar = theID[theID.length - 1];
      
      // Test new element
      console.log("New element's ID is: " + theID, "Array now contains: " + availableIDs);
      hideShow();
    }
} );

$(document).on("click", ".submit-source .remove-source", function() {  
    var theID = $(this).parent()[0].getAttribute("id");
    var theLastChar = theID[theID.length - 1];
    $(this).parent().remove();
  
 availableIDs.push(theLastChar);
    console.log("ID to be put back into array is: " + theLastChar, 
                "Array now contains: " + availableIDs);  
    hideShow();
} );

// Common function used when adding and removing:
function hideShow(lastChar){
  var $setToWorkOn = $(".submit-source .add-source");
  (availableIDs.length === 0) ? $setToWorkOn.hide() : $setToWorkOn.show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="submit-source">
 <span>Add up to 4 different sources.</span>
 <div id="source-wrap-1" class="source-wrap" >
  <input name="source-1" type="text"/>
 </div>
 <span class="add-source">add input</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks way better than what I did.  However it's behaving a bit weirdly. The available IDs are actually 2 3 and 4 (since the input #1 already exists).  But it looks like the script can't go up to 4 (so the condition to remove "Add input" is never met, do you know why ? I'm examining it right now, anyways thank you for your help :)

Comment: @eloism It's no problem. I can just change the values in the array. Let me do that. Either way, you can only add up to a total of 4 elements and the "add input" message only shows when appropriate.

Comment: Indeed, I just adapted it to my page and it runs without flaws. Also thank you a lot for commenting your code, it helped :)

Comment: @eloism  No problem! Don't forget to mark as the answer.